# Why there is a class name before the argument name in a function declaration?

Tags: php, class, laravel, model-view-controller, yii

I have seen this in the MVC frameworks.

```
Class Hotel{

function add(AddRequest $post){
$this->save($post->all());
}

}
```

Here "AddRequest" is a class which has been inherited.I dont quiet get the idea of it.All i knew is it binds/validates the arguments which has been passed into the function before being used in the function.Anyone can explain this well? How is the "AddRequest" is being implemented in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [type declaration](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) (formerly known as type hinting). The function will reject a `$post` passed to the function that's not of the `AddRequest` type.

If you're not explicitly injecting it yourself, chances are the framework is using [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) to automatically determine and inject the required dependency. As an example, Laravel [uses this fairly extensively](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/container#resolving) in version 5.

Comment: just wondering how it can be done.. automatic class injection, if there is no argument passed. Sounds like a lot of fun.